# RCP: Removing Title tab, minimize, maximize buttons from View

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I created Plugin Rcp project, with only one, standalone view.

When I run, I see minimize, maximize buttons and a tab with caption "View"

As you can see on the picture.
[image]

I want to remove all of that.
In Perspective  class, I set `setFixed(true)` but it's not helping.

```
public class Perspective implements IPerspectiveFactory {

    public void createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout) {
        layout.setEditorAreaVisible(false);
        layout.setFixed(true);

    }

}
```

I also tried suggested here: [enter link description here](http://andydunkel.net/eclipse/java/swt/2011/10/04/eclipse-rcp-remove-tab-folder-from-view.html)

e.g.

```
public class Perspective implements IPerspectiveFactory {
  public void createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout) {       
    String editorArea = layout.getEditorArea();
    layout.setEditorAreaVisible(false);

    layout.addStandaloneView(View.ID, false, IPageLayout.LEFT, 1.0f, editorArea);       
  }
}
```

When I run I don't see the view,only the shell.

**UPDATE**

If I change the ration parameter, to anything but 1.0f e.g.

```
layout.addStandaloneView(View.ID, false, IPageLayout.LEFT, 0.5f, editorArea);
```

I see the View but Tab and the buttons also there.

Comment: That second version should work, make sure you are specifying '-clean' when you run the RCP to clean up cached information about perspectives. Also does your view actually contain anything yet - if you don't have any controls in the view you won't see anything.

Comment: @greg-449, Of course I have controls, I also updated the post. When I run the application, I checked the 'Clear' chechbox

Comment: same is reproduced, if create plugin rcp project with single view template in eclipse.

Comment: I can't reproduce this, addStandaloneView works exactly as expected for me. What version of Eclipse is this?

Comment: If you are running Eclipse 4.2 (Juno) or 4.3 (Kepler) this is probably Eclipse bug [379803](http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=379803) which is fixed in Eclipse 4.4 (Luna)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. What I noticed is that I had defined a perspectiveExtension with my View inside my application's plugin.xml (before I tried to make the View standalone).

Removing the extension made the second version work.

This may not be the correct answer, but maybe it'll help someone who had the same issue.